# Data Migration not procceds after Map Step

Tags: data-migration, magento2.3.1

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-32-129:/var/www/magento$ sudo php bin/magento migrate:data -r vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/opensource-to-opensource/1.9.3.1/config.xml
Reset the current position of migration to start from the beginning

[2019-04-08 07:04:28][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: Data Integrity Step]: started
100% [============================] Remaining Time: < 1 sec
[2019-04-08 07:06:10][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: EAV Step]: started
100% [============================] Remaining Time: < 1 sec
[2019-04-08 07:06:13][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: Customer Attributes Step]: started
100% [============================] Remaining Time: < 1 sec
[2019-04-08 07:06:15][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: Map Step]: started
100% [============================] Remaining Time: < 1 sec
[2019-04-08 07:06:48][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: Url Rewrite Step]: started
100% [============================] Remaining Time: < 1 sec
[2019-04-08 07:06:48][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: Log Step]: started
100% [============================] Remaining Time: < 1 sec
[2019-04-08 07:06:49][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: Ratings Step]: started
100% [============================] Remaining Time: < 1 sec
[2019-04-08 07:06:49][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: ConfigurablePrices step]: started
100% [============================] Remaining Time: < 1 sec
[2019-04-08 07:06:49][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: OrderGrids Step]: started
100% [============================] Remaining Time: < 1 sec
[2019-04-08 07:06:49][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: Tier Price Step]: started
100% [============================] Remaining Time: < 1 sec
[2019-04-08 07:06:49][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: SalesIncrement Step]: started
100% [============================] Remaining Time: < 1 sec
[2019-04-08 07:06:49][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: Inventory Step]: started
100% [============================] Remaining Time: < 1 sec
[2019-04-08 07:06:49][INFO][mode: data][stage: setup triggers][step: Stage]: started
100% [============================] Remaining Time: < 1 sec
[2019-04-08 07:07:19][INFO][mode: data][stage: data migration][step: EAV Step]: started
100% [============================] Remaining Time: < 1 sec
[2019-04-08 07:07:30][INFO][mode: data][stage: volume check][step: EAV Step]: started
100% [============================] Remaining Time: < 1 sec
[2019-04-08 07:07:46][INFO][mode: data][stage: data migration][step: Customer Attributes Step]: started
100% [============================] Remaining Time: < 1 sec
[2019-04-08 07:08:02][INFO][mode: data][stage: volume check][step: Customer Attributes Step]: started
100% [============================] Remaining Time: < 1 sec
[2019-04-08 07:08:03][INFO][mode: data][stage: data migration][step: Map Step]: started
12% [===>------------------------] Remaining Time: 18 mins
```

**Magento not showing any kind of error only waiting time increase in map steps. Only customer migrate properly not any product etc 
Any one have idea how to debug this error.**

Source Magento have 9000 customer and 100 product and 13000 orders still it taking to much time process never terminated at **map step** only time increase not even showing any error.

If i check at admin and database only customer record and attributes are migrated..... not anything else... like orders...

**Source Magento : 1.9.3.1 

Destination Magento : 2.3.1**

Comment: How does this step gets terminated?

Comment: not terminated it go in infinete loop only time increase 1 hours , 2 hours  infinite nothing happing not shoowing any kind of error

Comment: Can you able to find if any data migrated to Magento 2 DB from Magento 1?

Comment: Customer migrated properly not anyting else ...

Comment: How much time you have waited?

Comment: 5-8 hours wait still no any error ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After Debugging at file

> :vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/src/Migration/Step/Map/Data.php

Print Source table name and destination table find that issue with

```
catalog_product_entity_media_gallery
```

crosscheck record so finds the issue and fixed that. issue related to orphan records so it failed and go to infinite loop so I just ignore that table because I just want to migrate customer and orders

Comment: i have same issue facing and how can solve it ?(http://prntscr.com/oshh6i) i have remove orphan some records

Comment: for debugging just print all query so u got an idea on which table it has an issue

Comment: this issue is solved it but currently i am facing this one  Notice: `Undefined offset: 19 in /home/m2/public_html/vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/src/Migration/Step/Eav/Data.php on line 278` you have an idea for that?

Comment: reset your database and try again ... in short try migration with fresh setup it due to some entry migrated in magento 2 dB

Comment: means magento1 and magento2 db also?

Comment: Magento 2 Database

Comment: ok Thanks......

Answer (score 2):

I realise you found the problem that was responsible in your particular case, but I thought I'd add an extra answer here, as my team had the same symptoms but a different explanation. Hopefully this will be of use to others.

**tl;dr:** We were migrating from USA to Europe and the latency was high. The migration hadn't got stuck, it was just incredibly slow. It would have taken days if we had persevered.

We left the data migration tool running overnight. After approx. 15 hours, it was still stuck on the map step, at 13%. The migration log file provided no clues. We monitored for half an hour and saw no change in the database. We figured it was stuck.

We were wrong. After some debugging we found that the data transformation took about 0.4 seconds per record, so after 15 hours it had only managed to process roughly 135,000 records. In a Magento database that's really not very much. Added to which, it operates in blocks of records, only updating the destination database once a block has been processed. In our case the block size was 50,000, so that explains why we saw no change in the database over the course of half an hour.

We eventually found the problem was database read latency. We were running the script in an EU-based machine, reading from a US database. When we ran the script on a US machine it was immeasurably faster (literally - the timestamps in our logging read 0 seconds per record).

Comment: thank you for your explanation. this was almost same issue with my migration today. Actually, I was migrating on local system but the data was from a different locale site, so this step got hanged and I started looking for solutions. You post came as rescue and I decided to wait. Well after 3 hours it moved to next step, finally...

Answer (score 1):

Same problem, but different reason, just give everyone a reference.

I put the debug codes `echo $sourceDocName.PHP_EOL;` in `\Migration\Step\Map\Data::perform` method, and found the reason.

My `sales_flat_quote` table has millions of data, when migration, it looks like stuck, but actually there is too much data to spend time. We need go to database to see the process.

When you have a very large table to migrate, it will looks like stuck. You need debug the `\Migration\Step\Map\Data::perform` method, sometime it is because the table is too large, sometime it is because the wrong data in table as others have answered, just note the last inserted data.